# Generate SQL Change Script of Data Changes Only (not schema)

Tags: sql, sql-server, change-script

Basically I need something to generate SQL Server change scripts for **data differences only**, based on the data differences between two tables with the same schema.

We will have a table with approx 250,000-330,000 rows and 10-12 columns, and two instances of the table:

1. The `Master` table, populated with records from the production system.
2. the `Sandpit` table, also populated from the production system - but in which the user can add / remove rows and edit cell contents.

Once the user is happy with their edits they need to generate a change script which makes the necessary changes to an instance of the Master table in a variety of servers (test, pre-prod, prod), so it needs to be reliable. It's safe to assume that all versions of the master data will be the same when the script is eventually run.

They also need to be able to re-run the change script for self-testing (restoring the master back to it's original state would be a separate process, out of scope for this question).

Design of the table schema is not yet done, and can be tailored to suit this purpose.
SQL Server 2008 Standard edition, upgrade likely (but still standard edition).

I understand RedGate is pretty much the industry standard / leading choice for generating SQL change scripts but their website focuses a lot on managing schema changes so not sure if it's appropriate to use here. I'm familiar with using SQL Server myself but it's been a few years - not sure if the inbuilt functionality is up to it or not (both being technically capable + user friendly enough). The end user will be a competent SQL user but comes from the business side not IT (not SQL Admin grade).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this from Visual Studio using SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools).  You need to do a data comparison between the source and target tables, which will then generate a change script.

Comment: Cheers Greg, unfortunately the person who needs to do this won;t have access to Visual Studio.